# Tkinter button stuck / frozen upon pressing until all the commands are executed

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

Just started with Tkinter and posting only the snippet of the code.
`label` and `button` are `Label` and `Button` class objects respectively.

When the button is pressed for the first time `on_button_click_organisation` is called which changes the `button` configuration and now when we click it `on_button_click_compute` is called, which is expected to perform a time taking action via the **`main`** method.

But the GUI gets stuck until the main() ends. How to stop this and make the button active once the excecution returns after computing main() and inactive till then?

```
def on_button_click_organisation(self):
    self.organisation_file = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("*.csv", "CSV")])
    print("Organisation File : " + self.organisation_file)
    self.label.config(text = "Start Code")
    self.button.config(text = "START", command = self.on_button_click_compute)


def on_button_click_compute(self):
    self.label.config(text = "Wait..\nResult being computed\n(Might take up to 15 minutes)")

    self.button.config(state = DISABLED)

    #Time taking task
    main(self.filename, self.organisation_file, self.result_folder)
    sleep(5) #To mimic time taking main() if main() returns in less time

    self.button.config(state = NORMAL)
    self.label.config(text = "Done..\nCheck the Result Folder")

    self.button.configure(text = "Finish", command=root.quit())
```

Comment: `self.button.configure(text = "Finish", command=root.quit())` will execute the `quit` command as soon as you create the button. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's another problem I noticed. Thanks for the heads up. I'll correct that when the bigger problem is solved :P

Comment: you have to use `thread` to run "long-running function" like `main()`.  Long-running function stops `mainloop()` and GUI doesn't work.

Comment: @furas I was afraid that would be the only solution.

Comment: sometimes long-running function can be redesigned so it can be executed many times for short time - and then `root.after()` can be used.

Comment: @furas In this case the long-running function doesn't have that benefit, threading seems to be the only way to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: the command is a callback, so instead of running `root.quit()`, you'll want `root.quit`.